# The nsInclude parameter of mongorestore is having no effect

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, mongorestore

I've been pouring over the mongorestore documentation trying to figure out why my mongorestore command is restoring *everything* in my collection, despite including `--nsInclude`

This is the command I have tried (I have also experimented with parameter order, which seems not to matter, as expected).

```
mongorestore --nsInclude=myns.mycollection --uri mongodb://user:pass@mongo/myns?authSource=admin --gzip --drop --preserveUUID --archive="/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz"
```

(if it matters) I created the file like this:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb://user:pass@mongo/myns?authSource=admin --gzip --archive="/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz"
```

Interestingly, my program output includes this statement:

```
The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}
```

(even though --db and --collection are nowhere in the command)

There are many examples online of mongorestore working well with --nsInclude. This surely isn't a bug, is it?

Full mongorestore output:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb://user:pass@mongo/myns?authSource=admin --gzip --archive="/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz"
The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}
preparing collections to restore from
reading metadata for myns.odwhoms from archive '/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz'
restoring myns.odwhoms from archive '/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz'
no indexes to restore
finished restoring myns.odwhoms (5 documents, 0 failures)
reading metadata for myns.audits from archive '/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz'
restoring myns.audits from archive '/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz'
no indexes to restore
finished restoring myns.audits (44 documents, 0 failures)
reading metadata for myns.odwhats from archive '/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz'
restoring myns.odwhats from archive '/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz'
no indexes to restore
finished restoring myns.odwhats (5 documents, 0 failures)
54 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Comment: I see on GitHub that the deprecated message may be a red herring related to using .bson.gz instead of just .bson. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/37bb4eddbb8d87a5aab3d75904382175127f0500/mongorestore/mongorestore.go#L227

Answer (score 7):

After some more experimenting, it seems that my connection string having the database name in it is what was implicitly setting the "--db" option internally. By also adding an --nsInclude parameter, I was merely re-specifying a collection that was already in scope to restore.

If I remove the DB name, nsInclude begins to work properly:

```
mongorestore --uri mongodb://user:pass@mongo/?authSource=admin --gzip --drop --preserveUUID --archive="/data/backups/myns/myns.bson.gz" --nsInclude=myns.mycollection
```