Mongorestore –gzip –archive restore only specific collection
I have MongoDB backup that was created in following way:
mongodump -h <host> -u <user> --password=<password> -d <db_name> --authenticationDatabase <db_name> --archive=<backup_name>.gz --gzip

When I’m restoring the backup using “mongorestore” all the DB content is being restored.
I’m looking for a way to restore only specific collection from the backup to a new or same DB.
I’ve tried to use --nsInclude, --nsFrom and --nsTo flags, but they aren’t helping.
Is there any possible way to achieve what I’ve described above?

Upd:
I've tried following:

as described in that post


to use --nsInclude, --nsFrom and --nsTo
In output I see that it's restoring all the collections and not one i specified in "--nsInclude=". I cannot share an output cause my MongoDB is running in air-gapped environment.


nsExclude or nsInclude should work. How did you run mongorestore?

@WernfriedDomscheit, this way:
mongorestore --archive=<path_to_your_archive> --gzip --nsInclude='.' --drop

Try --nsFrom='<db>.<collection>' --nsTo='<db>.<collection>'. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411661/the-nsinclude-parameter-of-mongorestore-is-having-no-effect It would be useful to provide also the output messages of  mongorestore - and please edit your questions for such information instead of adding a comment

@WernfriedDomscheit, i updated my question

Which version of mongorestore?

@Joe , it's 100.6.1
